# Cannot load nokogiri when installing rails_admin in rails 4.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When trying to run `rails g rails_admin:install` I get the following error:

```
/home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/nokogiri-1.6.0/lib/nokogiri.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-pjax-0.7.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:1:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-pjax-0.7.0/lib/rack/pjax.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-pjax-0.7.0/lib/rack-pjax.rb:2:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-pjax-0.7.0/lib/rack-pjax.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:7:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin.rb:1:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rails_admin-0.5.0/lib/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/website/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
  from /home/vieirater/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:4:in `require'
  from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why did you feel the need to comment on Rails 4.0?  Did this work on a Rails 3.2.x installation, but fail when you attempted to upgrade?

Comment: did you try `bundle exec rails generate rails_admin:install` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did try the bundle exec rails generate rails_admin:install but it gives me the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run

```
rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247 gem update --system
```

More detail [in this blog post on the very same issue](http://makandracards.com/makandra/18139-cannot-load-such-file-nokogiri-nokogiri-or-any-other-gem-with-native-extensions-on-rvm-and-ruby-2).

Comment: I tried rvm all do gem update --system and its successfully updated with all documentation installed, But when I run the rails g rails_admin:install, it gives me the same problem. Do you have any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: @PONCY it would be great if you could answer your own question with the actual fix in order to help future visitors. Then mark your answer as accepted so that your question is no longer listed as unanswered. Cheers!